# Check if record exists, if yes “update” if not “insert” using cursor sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger that after insert update and insert data in a table, using the if as paramter for the insert or update, at the same time i have another trigger after update that changes another register. The problem is that the first trigger when does the update it trigger the update trigger... So occours that I had to protect the first trigger by checking if there´s a register there before the insert BUT I have a cursor to insert the data in the middle of all this, after I did checking the insert of one register occurs BUT the others inside the cursor aren´t inserted in the table just one register of the list in the cursor... I cannot find the problem, please help...

this is my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_inclusao_dupla]  ON  [dbo].[tb_patrimonio]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

begin try
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
declare @id as int
declare @count as int
declare @qtd as int 
declare @emlote as bit
declare @nr_serie as varchar(100)
declare @nr_patrimonio as varchar(100)
declare @dm_identificado as bit
declare @nr_inventario as varchar(100)

set @nr_patrimonio = (select nr_patrimonio_efetivo from inserted)
set @nr_serie = (select nr_serie from inserted)
set @nr_inventario = (select nr_inventario from inserted)


/*single insert*/
    if (@nr_patrimonio is not null or @nr_serie is not null or @nr_inventario is not null)
        begin
            set @emlote =0
            declare registros cursor for
            select cd_patrimonio , nr_qtd_lote,nr_serie, nr_patrimonio_efetivo from inserted

            open registros
            fetch next from registros into @id, @qtd, @nr_serie, @nr_patrimonio
            while( @@fetch_status = 0)
            begin                                                           
                set @dm_identificado = 1

                update tb_patrimonio set dm_identificado = @dm_identificado, dm_em_lote = @emlote
                where cd_patrimonio = @id               
                end
            fetch next from registros into @id, @qtd,@nr_serie, @nr_patrimonio
            close registros
            deallocate registros

        end
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN           
        /*multiple insert*/     
        begin 
            set @emlote =0
            set @dm_identificado = 0
            declare registros2 cursor for
            select cd_patrimonio , nr_qtd_lote,nr_serie, nr_patrimonio_efetivo from inserted
                open registros2
                fetch next from registros2 into @id, @qtd, @nr_serie, @nr_patrimonio
                while( @@fetch_status = 0)
                begin   
                    print @qtd                              
                    set @count = 1
                    update tb_patrimonio set dm_identificado = @dm_identificado, dm_em_lote = @emlote
                    where cd_patrimonio = @id 

                    while (@count <= (@qtd-1))
                    begin       
                                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tb_patrimonio]
                                   ([dm_patrimonio]
                                   ,[dm_em_lote]
                                   ,[nr_qtd_lote]
                                   ,[cd_grupo_produto]
                                   ,[nm_patrimonio]
                                   ,[nr_patrimonio_efetivo]
                                   ,[nr_patrimonio_antigo]
                                   ,[nr_serie]
                                   ,[ds_descricao]
                                   ,[nr_lacre]
                                   ,[cd_barra]
                                   ,[dm_tipo_entrada]
                                   ,[nr_garantia]
                                   ,[cd_nota_fiscal]
                                   ,[ds_garantia]
                                   ,[img_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_situacao_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_orgao]
                                   ,[cd_local]
                                   ,[dm_situacao]
                                   ,[cd_usuario_inc]
                                   ,[cd_estado_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_tipo_posse]
                                   ,[cd_usuario_alt]
                                   ,[dt_alteracao]
                                   ,[cd_usuario]
                                   ,[dt_inclusao]
                                   ,[cd_estado_equipamento]
                                   ,[cd_fornecedor]
                                   ,[nr_termo]
                                   ,[img_termo]
                                   ,[dm_identificado]
                                   ,[dt_instalacao_equipamento]
                                   ,[nr_inventario])

                                    SELECT 
                                    [dm_patrimonio]
                                   ,@emlote
                                   ,[nr_qtd_lote]
                                   ,[cd_grupo_produto]
                                   ,[nm_patrimonio]
                                   ,[nr_patrimonio_efetivo]
                                   ,[nr_patrimonio_antigo]
                                   ,[nr_serie]
                                   ,[ds_descricao]
                                   ,[nr_lacre]
                                   ,[cd_barra]
                                   ,[dm_tipo_entrada]
                                   ,[nr_garantia]
                                   ,[cd_nota_fiscal]
                                   ,[ds_garantia]
                                   ,[img_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_situacao_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_orgao]
                                   ,[cd_local]
                                   ,[dm_situacao]
                                   ,[cd_usuario_inc]
                                   ,[cd_estado_patrimonio]
                                   ,[cd_tipo_posse]
                                   ,[cd_usuario_alt]
                                   ,[dt_alteracao]
                                   ,[cd_usuario]
                                   ,[dt_inclusao]
                                   ,[cd_estado_equipamento]
                                   ,[cd_fornecedor]
                                   ,[nr_termo]
                                   ,[img_termo]
                                   ,@dm_identificado
                                   ,[dt_instalacao_equipamento]
                                   ,[nr_inventario] 
                                   FROM inserted where cd_patrimonio = @id

                       set @count = @count + 1
                    end
                fetch next from registros2 into @id, @qtd,@nr_serie, @nr_patrimonio
                end
                close registros2
                deallocate registros2                         
        end
    END
end try
begin catch
    declare @errormessage nvarchar(4000)
    declare @errorseverity int
    declare @errorstate int

    select 
        @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @errorseverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @errorstate = ERROR_STATE()

    raiserror (     
              @errormessage,
              @errorseverity,
              @errorstate                 
              )

end catch end
```

Comment: You need to refactor this. What is it, a batch job? In that case, disabling the triggers and including that logic in the batch might help.

Comment: I can´t disable the triggers because the the system using this database is based on triggers that´s why I did the checking, because this after insert trigger triggers the update trigger.

Comment: I don´t get WHY the cursor stops working after i add the checking..

Comment: Run away from there....

Comment: If i could i would kkk

Comment: As coded this will never do anything. It is an INSERT trigger and the main conditional check is majorly flawed. There will NEVER be any rows in deleted in an insert trigger. Thank goodness that logical flaw is there or this nightmare of cursor ridden performance pig would have been released in the wild. This doesn't need to be reworked, it needs to be taken out back and shot. The ONLY way to fix is a complete rethinking of the entire process.

Comment: And to make matters even worse it is using a scalar value populated from inserted. If there is more than 1 row this whole thing is just flat out broken. This thing has so many performance problems it would be hard to list them all.

Comment: The solution for the problem was rethinking the process indeed...